# Explorer for blockchain

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockexplorer

I want to develop an explorer for coins(BTC,LTC,BCH,...), like [blockchair](https://blockchair.com/), or [blockchain](https://live.blockcypher.com/). I've searched a lot and I have found different answers. Finally, here is my solution. First, I use RPC to retrieve all blockchain data and insert them in a Mongo database. After retrieving all blocks data, I use the ZMQ feature of the core, to retrieve realtime blocks and transactions. Transactions will be saved in a separate (in memory) table which is the mempool table. Whenever a new block is found, I delete the mempool transactions which exists in the new block. I have some problems. The first problem is in finding UTXOs of addresses. The utxo query is complicated and takes a long time to respond(I've indexed the fields that uses in utxo query). My solution for this problem is preprocessing data before inserting them in DB and mark the spent outputs. There are other solutions too. One of them is parsing `chinstate/levelDB` files and extracting utxos. Should I change the schema of the DB for performance? I am confused. The second problem is mempool transactions. They will be lost when I reset the core(for mainteneance). So I lose the unconfirmed transactions. How should I handle them? I don't know whether my solutions are optimal or not? Any suggestions for solving the mentioned problem?

My MongoDB has two collections: blocks and transactions.
[image: transaction document sample]
[image: block document sample]